# Why does Scala reify not work as according to the docs?

Tags: scala, abstract-syntax-tree, reification

The Scala API docs for 2.10.3 say that I can, "Use refiy to produce the abstract syntax tree representing a given Scala expression." Accordingly, I can do:

```
scala> val uni = scala.reflect.runtime.universe 
uni: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse = scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse@4e42766

scala> uni reify { 1 to 3 } 
res2: uni.Expr[scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive] = Expr[scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive](Predef.intWrapper(1).to(3))
```

In the example above, I get what I am looking for: `Predef.intWrapper(1).to(3))` (a handy expanded representation of the operations to be performed).

When I attempt to reify `1 + 3`, however, I do not the representation of the operations to perform that I desire.

```
scala> uni reify { 1 + 3 }
res5: uni.Expr[Int(4)] = Expr[Int(4)](4)
```

Is this expected behavior? Is `+` a primitive operation and, hence, not reified?

The Scala docs show an example of reification that implies that an even more useful representation is available:

```
reify{ 2 + 4 } // Apply( Select( Literal(Constant(2)), newTermName("$plus")), List( Literal(Constant(4)) ) )
```

How can I examine the proper expanded representation for `1 + 3` (if one exists) and how can I retrieve a detailed representation of any expression (immediately above)?

**Edit:** I see now that the representation show in the Scala docs is generated by `showRaw`. However, I still cannot reproduce the raw representation show in the example above for `2 + 4`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242428/is-there-a-way-to-test-at-compile-time-that-a-constant-is-a-compile-time-constan/21244494#21244494) by Eugene Burmako:

> macros are wired into typechecking (in the sense that macro arguments
>   are typechecked prior to macro expansion), and typechecking folds
>   constants

`reify` is implemented using macro.

You should just prevent constant folding like this:

```
{
  val i = 1
  showRaw{ reify{i + 2}.tree }
}
// Apply(Select(Ident(newTermName("i")), newTermName("$plus")), List(Literal(Constant(2))))
```

Comment: In order to use the your workaround, I would have to alter the code I am reifying. This is not always easy. Is there no other way?

Comment: Also, are the Scala docs for 2.10.3 wrong when it shows `reify{ 2 + 4 } // Apply( Select( Literal(Constant(2)), newTermName("$plus")), List( Literal(Constant(4)) ) )`?

Comment: @AndrewMcKinlay: Note that in compile time `2 + 4` will be folded to `6` so there will be only a constant `6` in runtime. I don't know other way to prevent constant folding. If you are developing some kind of DSL you could use string interpolation like `math"1 + 2"`.

Comment: @AndrewMcKinlay: I guess it's from an old version of macros behavior.

Comment: So, did the previous macro system not type check macro arguments?

Comment: @AndrewMcKinlay: No, macros without arguments type check are `White Box macros` (see [Evolution of Scala Macros](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/scala-macros)), and they will be introduced only in `2.12`. I don't know the history of this error in documentation.

Comment: Fixed the docs: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/3414. That's a plain oversight in the documentation - macros have never behaved this way. Thanks for catching it and sorry for the confusion.