# Using Java 8 is there a way to validate/assert that a constant is a compile-time constant?

Tags: java, java-8

I'd like to have a JUnit test that verifies a specific constant is a Compile-Time Constant.
How would I go about doing that?

I found a solution for Scala, but I'd like on for plain Java.
[Is there a way to test at compile-time that a constant is a compile-time constant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242428/is-there-a-way-to-test-at-compile-time-that-a-constant-is-a-compile-time-constan)

Root Cause:

`The value for annotation attribute ApiModelProperty.allowableValues must be a constant expression`

What I'd like in a Unit Test:

```
    validateCompileTimeConstant(SomeClass.CONSTANT_VALUE, "Message Here!!");
```

Usage

```
    @ApiModelProperty(name = "name", required = true, value = "Name", allowableValues=SomeClass.API_ALLOWABLE_VALUES, notes=SomeClass.API_NOTES)
    private String name;
```

SomeClass

```
public enum SomeClass {
    BOB(4,  "Bob"),//
    TED(9,  "Ted"),//
    NED(13, "Ned");

    public static final String API_ALLOWABLE_VALUES = "4,9,13,16,21,26,27,170";
    public static final String API_NOTES = "4 - Bob\n" +
                                           "9 - Ted\n" +
                                           "13 - Ned";

    public int code;
    public String desc;

    private ContentCategoryCode(int code, String desc) {
        this.code = code;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public static final String apiAllowableValues() {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        for (ContentCategoryCode catCode : values()) {
            b.append(catCode.code);
            b.append(',');
        }
        b.setLength(b.length()-1);
        return b.toString();
    }

    public static final String apiNotes() {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        for (ContentCategoryCode catCode : values()) {
            b.append(catCode.code).append(" - ").append(catCode.desc);
            b.append('\n');
        }
        b.setLength(b.length()-1);
        return b.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not something you would test at runtime. By its very essence, the misuse of a compile time constant would fail at compile time, where it would be detected by the compiler.

Comment: You shouldn't write code which depends on this one way or another.

Comment: I can only second @Savior. Why run a unit test when the compiler did already tell you that there is an error?

Comment: It's more so I can document the fix if someone tries to generate the value of the constant. Essentially, I want the "Why it failed to compile" in the unit test class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Error Prone](https://errorprone.info/) project has a `@CompileTimeConstant` annotation which can be used to enforce exactly this.

It's not a test that you run with JUnit, but a compiler plug-in that enforces this (and other bug patterns) at compile time.

Here is the documentation: https://errorprone.info/bugpattern/CompileTimeConstant

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating my own annotation, since it required less setup than using Error Prone.

#### Annotation Class:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface TestCompileTimeConstant {
    public String key() default "";
}
```

#### JUnit Test:

```
public class SomeClassTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals(SomeClass.API_ALLOWABLE_VALUES, SomeClass.apiAllowableValues());
        assertEquals(SomeClass.API_NOTES, SomeClass.apiNotes());
    }

    @Test
    @TestCompileTimeConstant(key=SomeClass.API_ALLOWABLE_VALUES)
    public void testIsCompileTimeConstant1() {
        //Pass - If this doesn't compile, you need to make sure API_ALLOWABLE_VALUES doesn't call any methods.
    }

    @Test
    @TestCompileTimeConstant(key=SomeClass.API_NOTES)
    public void testIsCompileTimeConstant2() {
        //Pass - If this doesn't compile, you need to make sure API_NOTES doesn't call any methods. 
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need for `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME` here. Otherwise, this seems like a reasonable solution.