# How to define a constant members in Scala?

Tags: scala

What is the correct was to define a constant such as Pi or the Golden Ratio in a Scala program?

As an example, in C# I can do this:

```
class Example
{
    public readonly static Double GoldenRatio;

    static Example ()
    {
        GoldenRatio = (1.0 + Math.Sqrt (5.0)) / 2.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's considered bad practice to have public variables. Consider using Properties instead. `public static double GoldenRatio {get; private set;}` should do the trick

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It would be just a `val` member:

```
object Example {
  val GoldenRatio = (1.0 + Math.sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0
}
```

Also, take a look at the [Scala Style Guide section regarding constants](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html#constants-values-variable-and-methods).

Comment: When, exactly, will the expression get evaluated?

Comment: @Pooky the expression is evaluated immediately. If you want it to be evaluated when it's first called use `lazy val` if you want it to be evaluated every time it's called use `def`

Comment: @Pooky if you're looking for compile-time evaluation, you can make it "final val". See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11197537/303940. In the case of the GoldenRatio, however, which requires some math to be performed, you may need to use a Macro to evaluate during compile time and turn it into a literal.

Comment: @ElectricCoffee: No it is not evaluated immediately, but the first time when the defining object is called.

Comment: @sschaef I would've assumed the object, being a singleton is evaluated at declaration

Comment: @ElectricCoffee The class file containing the object needs to be loaded, and its initialization is only run then.